# mysql relational database, relationships and logic

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

I am currently creating a system for a school and I am looking for some reinforcement for my thinking, or alternatively some guidance and be told to go back to the drawing board.

Currently I am little bit confused (or over thinking) by how my relationships should work because of the various types of user that my system has (all of the users need to the ability to log in).

**User Types**

Superusers
Admins
Teachers
Teaching Admins
Students
Parents

So far I thinking this best way for this work is to have a central users table that would have similar schema to this,

```
  `id`,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `banned` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `invite_code` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `role` INT NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NULL,
  `deleted_at` DATETIME NULL
```

My thinking is the role column would identify the type of user they are, I would then have a m:m relationship with the schools table to allow for teachers for that work across multiple schools, and each student, teacher/teaching admin and admin would have a relationship with a school. In my head this all works fine.

My confusion comes with the parents, each user(students) can have many parents, the parents also need to be able to log in so need an entry in the users table, but how can I create a relationship between a student and parent?

I have 2 thoughts at the moment,

1) Create a parents table that consists of the columns, id, user_id, parent_to. With the user_id beign the user entry for the parent and the the parent_to being the id of the student user.

2) Create a new column in the user table that can be nullable that stores the ID's of parents user id if they that row is a student row?

I have also wondered if maybe I could things like has many through, or polymorphic relations. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Your first thought would be my choice, but you don't need to add an id column to it. A composite primary key on the two foreign key columns will work well. Also, I suggest you name the two columns parent_id and student_id, since both are recorded in the users table a user_id column is ambiguous.

Comment: Also look into supertype / subtype tables if you want to model or record attributes and relationships that only apply to a particular kind of user.

Answer (score 0):

Your #1 option is a "link table" - a better approach, allowing many-to-many relationship between parents and students.

P.S. You are not going to store passwords in a plain text, right?